# Why Visual Studio NoMad project not showing "jQuery UI Designer Page" items?

Tags: c#, cordova, visual-studio-2013, mobile-application, visual-studio-extensions

I'm new with nomad extension for visual studio (develop mobile applications based on phonegap project). As you can see at this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/developers/articles/building-hybrid-cross-platform-apps-an-introduction-to-nomad-for-visual-studio/ at some point the example add new item of type jQuery UI Designer Page to the project. In my Visual Studio I can't see this kind of file. How can I add this kind of file?
When I try to Add --> new item (in Visual Studio project) I can see only css, javascript and html files.
I've tried everything.
Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nomad team answered me in a email about this question:

> Hi,
>
> We removed that feature when we moved to be backed by PhoneGap Build.
>
> Thanks.